# Best way to append and check file location

Tags: python, shutil

```
elif user == str(3):
    src = input("Enter the location of the file you wish to copy: ")
    print('\n')
    dstLocation = input("Next, enter the location where you wish to copy the file to (DO NOT ENTER FILE): ") #asks user to input destination location
    dstFile = input("Enter the file name and extension: (e.g. abc.txt) ") #ask user to input destination filename
    dst = os.path.join(dstLocation, dstFile) #Appends the dstLocation and dstFile
    if os.path.isfile(src) and os.path.isdir(dstLocation):
        while count < 1:
            shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
            print('Copy successful')
            count = count + 1
    else:
        print('Copy unsuccessful')
```

I'm still learning Python, but besides the try-except method, is this a adequate way for appending a file for copying.

Also is there a way to use switch statements, or are multiple if statements acceptable in Python

Comment: Python has no `switch` statement :)

Comment: what is count? it seems to do nothing

Comment: I got rid of count. I just realize, you're right it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, but as pointed out by others `count` is not necessary.

As you mention yourself, the try-except method would be more proper than using `if-else`. You could then also give a more precise error statement than only saying `Copy unsuccessful`) and - if wanted - add `exit(1)`.

There is no `switch` statement in python. Usual workarounds are using dictionaries or multiple `if-elif` constructs.